# Module 2D array passing

Tags: arrays, module, verilog

in the HEADMODULE I create 2D array 'data' and I want to use it as a memory / storage.
In STRCNVTDATA I assign it to the input I have (sinus waves).
In SHWAMPLITUDE I want to show the amplitude of the data on LEDs .

My problem is the data cannot be passed.

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:661  'shwamplitude.v'  Non-net port data cannot be of mode input
```

**HEADMODULE**

```
module SPI_Lab (...);
...
wire [7:0] data [99999999:0];
...
strcnvtdata M8 (CCLK, transfer, tmpdata, storagecount, data); 
shwamplitude M6 (CCLK, storagecount, data, mled); 

endmodule
```

**STRCNVTDATA**

```
module strcnvtdata(input clk, transfer, [7:0] tmpdata, output reg storagecount, output reg [7:0] data [99999999:0]);
always @(posedge clk)
 begin
    if (transfer==1)
        data[storagecount] = tmpdata;  

        storagecount = storagecount + 1'b1; 

    if (storagecount == 99999999)
        storagecount = 0;

end
endmodule
```

**SHWAMPLITUDE**

```
module shwamplitude(input clk, input storagecount, input reg [7:0]data[99999999:0] , output reg [7:0] mled);
reg [7:0] amplitude;

always @(posedge clk)
 begin

    if (data[storagecount] > data[storagecount-1])
        amplitude = data[storagecount];

    mled = amplitude;
 end 
endmodule
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the vhdl tag? Can you pass 2D arrays as port signals in VHDL? Yes you can.  Should you be passing  100 million member arrays? Tools generally can't deal with stack storage that big and the simulation throughput rate would be abysmal. Can you avoid passing the array? You could in VHDL, making the two 'modules' process statements in the same scope (a memory 'module'), although it wouldn't help in elaborating a model with an array that large. The memory could be abstracted creating a foreign model or reduced in size for simulation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional arrays cannot be used as inputs or outputs in verilog.

If you are trying to create a memory type module, the way those usually work is to have an input write data, input address, input read/write controls, and an output read data.

If you don't want to use this type of address/data semantics, you can flatten your array into a single huge bus, though that's probably not ideal, and not how real hardware would be designed.

Comment: Why not use the system verilog to pass the array? Not really applicable in this case but generally better than flattening the array and reassembling it on the other side.